# Шрифты сайта в ubuntu linux или как определить ОС?

Tags: css, linux, ос, шрифты

Для сайта установили нестандартные шрифты с помощью css.
В винде полнота и стиль шрифта, размер, красиво и гармонично смотрятся.
В Маке тоже все ок.
В линуксе все как-то размыто, чересчур жирно, из-за этого нектоторые блоки в верстке поехали и все отображается крайне некрасиво, даже если все выровнять.

Понимаем, что каждая операционная система и браузер по-разному рендерят шрифты, но возможно ли определить ОС и прописать для нужной ОС свою таблицу стилей со стандартными шрифтами?

Или все же есть выход с самими шрифтами?

Comment: https://capyba.ru/services/fontfinder/ - сервис автоматического определения всех шрифтов на странице по ссылке

Answer (score 2):

[User-Agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/) еще никто не отменял...
Вот, собственно, из этой записи и определяем систему, браузер и прочее.